# Excel 2010 date formatting not working on some cells but on others

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, excel-2010

In Excel 2010, I have a range of what looks like dates. When I attempt to format them only some changed the others remain unchanged. To be clear the right aligned 'dates' change and the left aligned 'dates' do not. (refer to 'Column M') I can format the right aligned dates into anything else such as percentage, general etc. whatever. The right aligned dates change and the left aligned remain unchanged even though they are also selected.

I can edit the left aligned cells i.e. change the value I see.

From looking I thought the left aligned dates were text. I read that text has an apostrophe before it in the formula bar, these do not, but could still be text. I am not sure.

What I have tried:

1) Using '=DATEVALUE'. This does not work. 
2) Formatting to date, copying cells to notepad and copying them back. This doesn't work. 
3) Using 'Text to Columns' button. Delimited option, then next, buttons unchecked, then next, then choosing 'DMY' and hitting Finish button. This does not work.

My formula is correct as you can see by the example I put in, in 'Column L'. I entered those dates manually and they work as expected. 'Column M' is the one of interest. It displays the #VALUE! error. Image attached.

Any assistance one could provide is greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what else to try.

To reiterate 'Column L' is the one I want to change. I want them all to be date values.

[image: Column L on left and Column M on right]

Thank you for your help.

I have updated the question with a picture of the image. I have formatted the same cells with date, currency 0 decimal and to text. You can see how the right sided cells morph into something different unrelated (it appears) to their date format. This is the problem. I am not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: What is short date type of your system? Assume `ddmmyyyy`. So, when you enter something like `19/19/2013` how month can be 19? Right?

Comment: It is coming from an american style source. So the format is MMDDYYYY. I am in the UK, and would be on the UK version. If that helps. I only need to interogate the year i.e. get those less than 2009 so the month and days aren't too much of an issue for me. I just need to get it into a date format. Thanks.

Comment: You have excel-vba as a tag for this question.  Do you have any VBA code associated with these fields?

Comment: No I don't. I assumed I would need some to solve this, I am open to suggestions. An answer may include VBA, hence the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too long to fit in a Comment. The left-aligned ones are strings, which can be manipulated into date/time serial numbers recognised by Excel (where not nonsense like 19/19/2013). At the moment they are US format (MDY) and the "months" (in your configuration) exceed `12`. The real problem however is the ones Excel *has* recognised, because it has created date/time serial numbers for these - but not the right ones. So `05/02/2013` it believes to be February 5, whereas if from the same source and hence style as the other dates, it actually is supposed to represent May 2.

Conversion of both text and 'wrong' dates into 'conventional' date serial numbers is possible but much more work than stepping back a stage and 'feeding' Excel with the 'right' data to begin with. For example keying it in 'properly' in the first place, rearranging the format in the source, or importing it with appropriate conversion from MDY to DMY (eg step 3 of 3 in the Text Import Wizard).

---

*Edit re comment*

**Be it upon your own head** but for "how I could modify 'left aligned' values (strings) to dates?":

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A4,4),LEFT(A4,FIND("/",A4,2)-1),MID(A4,FIND("/",A4)+1,2))
```

For "I am only interest in the year part" maybe (this is 'safe'):

```
=IFERROR(YEAR(A4),RIGHT(A4,4))+0
```

---

*Also, to explain the 'odd' four digit values*

Taking the last for example (`02/08/2012`) it is a representation of February 8, 2012, which in Excel's 1900 date system is a date serial number of 40947 (*roughly* the number of days since 1/1/1900, when the 'meter started'). The four digits furthest to the right are `0947`.

Switching to the first example (`02/05/2013`) that is a representation of February 5, 2013. Almost a full year (363 days) later than the last example.  Ignoring the thousands, 947 (from above) + 363 = `1310`.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response. This is a bigger data set i.e. thousands of dates, I can't necessarily change these manually anyway. Whether its DD/MM/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY is ok for me as I am only interest in the year part. So do you know how I could modify 'left aligned' values (strings) to dates?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the update. I have edited my question to show you the problem. I am unable to extract substrings from the 'right aligned' cells. You can see the value in the cell changes dramatically when I apply different formats.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the info. For your 2nd formula to get the date, I get a #VALUE error for the left aligned dates and the right aligned dates gives me the 4 numbers of the date serial number i.e. 02/05/2013 returns 1310 as in my image above. The =Right() function I am using returns the date for left aligned and the date serial representation for right aligned. For right aligned I require the year. i.e. for 02/05/2013 I need 2013 not 1310. Any suggestions on how to get that?

Comment: To clarify on the dates, Right() function gets me the year i.e. '2013' for left aligned cells whilst for right aligned cells it returns date serial representation i.e. '1310'. Year() function gets me year for right aligned cells. It returns a #VALUE! error when it is used on left aligned cells. So I need a way of getting the year from date serial representation cells.

Comment: Got it. I am also using =date(year(a1),month(a1),day(a1)) on serial representation numbers and I can get the right dates now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've had the same problem (after formatting, some cells were o.k. while some were not). 
What worked for me was:

1. Select the entire range of interest.
2. Format the range to the wanted date format (one corresponding to the already existing layout of the dates, i.e. if what you now have is 1/15/14, then use "English US" and choose, for example, "March 4, 2011" format - the point here being that you match the format with the layout you have (MM/DD/YY = MM/DD/YY).
3. Go to "Data", go to "Text to Columns", go "Delimiters", eliminate all delimiters, go next, select date and choose the format corresponding to your selected date format (in my case I chose MDY).
   Thank you all for your input.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what you are asking for exactly, but it seems like you want to reformat a US based date to a European format.  If i deciphered your question correctly, then maybe the below will help.

[image]

The formula in the cell beneath 'European' is `=TEXT(A2,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Review this link for more information: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx

Can you please elaborate on how the image below does not fit your needs?
[image]

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the response. I just tried your formula above and nothing changes. I'm not necessarily trying to change from American to European. There are some values (right aligned) that change when I format them i.e to percentage, decimal etc. Left aligned stay the same and do not change. I have no affect on them.

Comment: Also, try this after you have selected which format you want on the original column. http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/357010-time-format-cell-does-not-update-until-i-double-click-cell.html

Comment: FYI, `=Right()` will not work when using a date format.  You must use `=Text()`

Comment: Hi - You see I updated my question. You can see in the column N I am using the Right() function. You will see it gets the date for left aligned cells but not for right aligned cells. I need to get the year for the cells on the right opposed to the number that is currently given. The Text() function does not work on the cells. It returns an error. (Err:508 on open office)

Comment: Open Office...  That information would have been great to know at the very beginning...

Answer (score 1):

I've had all exactly the same problems - some fields changing and others not.

Turns out the fields that didn't change had a space after the data (already present when imported into Excel).

I Removed the space and excel instantly changed it into desired format!