# Excel text to date format issue

Tags: excel, date, format

I have the same issue as this OP when trying to change the date format

[Excel 2010 date formatting not working on some cells but on others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26935742/excel-2010-date-formatting-not-working-on-some-cells-but-on-others)

The solution does work on converting those 'Text' to date format. However for the other datas in the same column which are in 'Date' format they give a #VALUE! error as shown in the image below when the entire column uses the formula.

Is there anyway to resolve this issue other than manually keying in the date which does not need to be fix, as I'm afraid in the future I might have more than a few thousands date to manually change

The formula I've used is this which the entire column uses,

> =DATE(RIGHT(A2,4),LEFT(A2,FIND("/", A2,2)-1),MID(A2,FIND("/",A2)+1,2))

[image]

Comment: first convert to text. `Text(A2,"@")` then do the left/right/find on that.

Comment: So just convert everything at the left column which consist of the "Text" and "Date" to Text, then left/mid/right the column which everything have been converted to text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data in column A is a mixture of text that looks like dates, and real dates. All rows with the error have the dates as real dates and the left/right/mid functions don't work on the format but on the underlying value, which in the case of the dates is a number. Try it just `=RIGHT(A4,4)` to see what I mean.

In order to run the formula, all data needs to be text. You can quickly convert the data to text by selecting column A, then click Data > Text to columns > Next > Next > Select "Text" in step 3 and click Finish.

The data will be converted to text and all your error values will disappear.

Comment: Hi! , Thank you for your help, yes it works. Just another issue is there a way to like add a "0" infront of those "Text" which are single digits e.g 4/9/2017 to 04/09/2017, to prevent the error

Comment: The Left() will be OK, the Mid() is the problem, since the two characters after the first `/` may contain a `/`. You can use Substitute() to strip that out. `SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("/",A3)+1,2),"/","")` and the complete formula is `=DATE(RIGHT(A3,4),LEFT(A3,FIND("/", A3,2)-1),SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("/",A3)+1,2),"/",""))`

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much for helping! Much appreciation for your time!